# XOR to switch between two numbers, how about mod?

Tags: xor

I want to find an alternative index of an item, and the item can be switched back to its original index.
For now, the solution is not perfect -

Say an item's tag is in index1 originally, and I want to move it to index2

So `index2 = (index1 ^ tag) % max_index`

And if I want to move it back to index1

Just `index1 = (index2 ^ tag) % max_index`

The above equality only holds when max_index is the power of 2.

ex:

( **15** ^ 123 ) % 64 == **52**

( **52** ^ 123 ) % 64 == **15**

but

( **15** ^ 123 ) % 60 == **56**

( **56** ^ 123 ) % 60 == 7 (**!= 15**)

I wonder if there is other math operations that allows max_index to be any number.

---

EDIT:

I need to use the same operation to achieve switching between two index.

My scenario is - I have a hash table that each bucket can store at most 4 items, and it stores only an item's fingerprint (say 8 bit). If the bucket is full, I need to move an item's fingerprint to its alternative position without knowing its original representation. And once moved to the alternative position, the fingerprint can be moved back to its original position using the same operation as the previous one (Because I don't know if a fingerprint's current position is original or alternative).

Now - 
`index = (index1 ^ Hash(tag)) % max_index`

Comment: You may like [cuckoo hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing). That said, your motivation leaves much to be desired: 1. Why store only a fingerprint? 2. Why does it need to move back with the same operation? 3. Why does it need to move using only the fingerprint?

Comment: Actually, it's the design of [cuckoo filter](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf). But it need to make the size of the filter power of 2.

Comment: Thanks, that explains much of the motivation. I will try to update my answer this afternoon with some further thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition and subtraction work fine; if

```
index2 = (index1 + tag) % max_index
```

then

```
index1 = (index2 - tag) % max_index
```

In some languages, `%` is implemented strangely for negative numbers; if this is a concern for you, you may use

```
index1 = (index2 + max_index - tag) % max_index
```

to avoid issues.

---

After some shower thinking, I propose the following protocol. First choose your favorite symmetric block cipher; constraints on the cipher are:

- plaintext space must have at least `max_index` elements
- ciphertext space should not be too much bigger than `max_index` elements
- key space should probably be larger than your tag space (not a hard requirement)

Then you follow the following procedure to swap indices:

```
do { index = encrypt(tag, index); } while(index >= max_index);
do { index = index ^ 1;           } while(index >= max_index);
do { index = decrypt(tag, index); } while(index >= max_index);
```

If the size of the ciphertext space is `c*max_index`, this will take `c` encryptions and `c` decryptions in expectation. The index you get out the other end will be the same as it started with low probability -- it can only happen when either the index encrypts to `max_index-1` (and `max_index` is odd) or the encryption maps two adjacent values to two adjacent values.

Comment: It looks fine !
But what if (index2 + max_index - tag) is still negative?

Comment: @Leo Under the assumption that `index2` is nonnegative and `tag` is smaller than `max_index` -- which both seem like reasonable assumptions to me -- then `index2 + max_index - tag` will be nonnegative.

Comment: @Danial Wagner, Sorry In my scenario, tag may be bigger than max_index.
In python, the negative works fine, but in C it will be wrong.

Comment: @Leo If `tag` can be bigger than `max_index`, then you can use `(index2 + max_index - (tag % max_index)) % max_index`.

Comment: @Leo And again I want to reiterate that these tricks are needed only in languages that do negative modulus arithmetic badly. Try `(-1) % 2` to find out: if you get `-1`, then you need these tricks, but if you get `1`, you're fine with the simplest version.

Comment: @Danial Wagner Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: @Danial Wagner, Sorry that my scenario cannot know if the current index is index1 or index2, so the XOR can work (Same operation). But your operations are + and - (Need to know if the current index is index 1 or 2). Do you know any alternative solution that use the same operation ?

Comment: @Leo At this point, the requirements have changed enough times that I think you should write a bit about the bigger picture. What goal are you trying to achieve with these operations? What are the exact properties that you need of your operations? Apparently you want an indexed family of automorphisms that are self-inverse; do you need any other properties? If so, what, exactly? (For example, although `index2 = index1` satisfies my proposed properties, presumably it is no good for some reason. Can you say exactly what would go wrong with your intended application?)